# Matched Geometry Effect with AsyncImage iOS 15

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios15, swiftui-geometryeffect, swiftui-asyncimage

Consider the following example:

```
    struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showSplash: Bool = true
    @Namespace var animationNamespace

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if showSplash {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/seed/864a5875-6d8b-43d6-8d65-04c5cfb13f3b/1920/1440")) { image in
                        image.resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "SplashImage", in: animationNamespace)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        .clipped()
                    } placeholder: {
                        Color.gray
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    toggleSplashScreen(false)
                }
            } else {
                ScrollView {
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/seed/864a5875-6d8b-43d6-8d65-04c5cfb13f3b/1920/1440")) { image in
                            image
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "SplashImage", in: animationNamespace)
                                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                        } placeholder: {
                            Color.gray
                        }
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 400)
                        .clipped()
                    }
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        toggleSplashScreen(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With a helper method here:

```
private extension ContentView {
    func toggleSplashScreen(_ toggle: Bool) {
        withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.85, dampingFraction: 0.95)) {
            showSplash = toggle
        }
    }
}
```

This produces:

[image: Demo]

I noticed two things here that I would like to fix

1. The flashing white effect when transitioning between the two states.
2. I noticed since we are using `AsyncImage`, when `showSplash` changes the AsyncImages only sometimes hits the `placeholder` block. As a result, the transition becomes really choppy. I tested this with a static image from the assets file and the transition then became smooth. I also tried creating a Caching mechanism on the AsyncImage but still had issues with it hitting `placeholder` block sometimes.

Would love to hear any ideas :) Thanks!

Comment: `MatchedGeometry` effects are a little more involved than what you have. [SwiftUI Lab](https://swiftui-lab.com) has a great series of posts on this and advanced animations. I think the problem that you are having is that you are not giving the `MatchedGeometry` the information it needs to seamlessly translate between the two views, and so you are getting the behavior you are seeing. `MatchedGeometry` needs a way of calculating what the in between transitions should look like that doesn't exist in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things that I think you could do to improve this.

First, You are fighting a little bit against the way SwiftUI maintains a view's identity.  One of the ways that SwiftUI determines when it can reuse an existing structure as opposed to recreating a structure, is by it's location in the view hierarchy.  So when you toggle your structure you go from:

```
GeometryReader 
  AsyncImage
```

to

```
ScrollView
  GeometryReader
    AsyncImage
```

As a result, the system thinks these are two `AsyncImage` views and so it's rebuilding the view (and reloading the image) every time.  I think that's where your white flashes come from since you're seeing your gray placeholder in the middle of your animation.  If you could leave the scroll view in place, possibly disabling scrolling when it's not needed (if that's possible) then the OS could maintain the identity of the `AsyncImage`. (see https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/)

That leads to the second area of investigation for you.  `AsyncImage` is wonderful in the convenience it gives you in loading content from the network.  Unfortunately it doesn't make that communication faster.  Your goal should be to have `AsyncImage` go to the network as few times as possible.

Right now, your resizing strategy focuses on resizing the image.  That means that for every transition you're "hitting the network" (read putting your code on the slow, dusty, dirt road path).  Instead of resizing the image, you should just load the image once (the slow part) and resize the view that is displaying it.  The general idea would be to let `AsyncImage` load the image, then control how the image is animated by animating the frame of the view.

This is where I get less helpful.  I don't know enough about `AsyncImage` to know if it's capable of implementing that strategy.  It seems that it should be... but I don't know that it is.  You might have to resort to downloading and storing the image as state separately from the view that presents it.

So my advice is to limit the number of times `AsyncImage` has to reload the network data.  That involves helping SwiftUI maintain the identity of the `AsyncImage` so it doesn't have to reload each time the view is created.  And, try to implement your animations and scaling on the view, not the image, because rescaling the image also requires a network reload.

Answer (score 0):

Using matchedGeometryEffect with AsyncImage can be challenging, specially when the image aspect ratio changes during animation. A reliable approach I use to solve this issue is to overlay AsyncImage over a Rectangle and apply matchedGeometryEffect to the Rectangle.

Ensure the image is resizable, and choose between .scaleToFit() or .scaleToFill(). Then control the position and size of the image by modifying the rectangle itself.

if you want .scaleToFill(), then you have to crop the rectangle before applying the matchedGeometryEffect modifier.

```
ZStack {
    if showSplash {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.gray)
                .overlay {
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/seed/864a5875-6d8b-43d6-8d65-04c5cfb13f3b/1920/1440")) { image in
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                    } placeholder: {
                        Color.clear
                    }
                }
                .clipped()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "SplashImage", in: animationNamespace)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onTapGesture {
            toggleSplashScreen(false)
        }
    } else {
        ScrollView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.gray)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .overlay {
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/seed/864a5875-6d8b-43d6-8d65-04c5cfb13f3b/1920/1440")) { image in
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                        } placeholder: {
                            Color.clear
                        }
                    }
                    .clipped()
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "SplashImage", in: animationNamespace)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 400)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                toggleSplashScreen(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```